# how to register ejabberd user from php?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, ejabberd

I found a code from stack follow to execute the register command in ejabberd xmpp chat server using php. ([Create ejabberd user from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626897/create-ejabberd-user-from-php))

I also add "www-data ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/ejabberdctl" line in "/etc/sudoers" file in ubuntu linux server 12.0

But when i execute the file i got error:

"read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Host key verification failed."

The php code i am using as follows:

```
`<?php
$username = 'tester';
$password = 'testerspassword';
$node = 'myserver.com';
exec('sudo /usr/sbin/ejabberdctl register '.$username.' '.$node.' '.$password.' 2>&1',$output,$status);
if($output == 0)
{
    // Success!
}
else
{
    // Failure, $output has the details
    echo '<pre>';
    foreach($output as $o)
    {
        echo $o."\n";
    }
    echo '</pre>';
}
?>`
```

Please help me!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi The following code is working for me..

Just change the one line on above code

`exec('sudo -u ejabberd ejabberdctl register '.$username.' '.$node.' '.$password.' 2>&1',$output,$status);`

Comment: Hi mani i use the above code on my ubnutu 14.04 LTS machine but it gives following error to me "sudo: unknown user: ejabberd" "sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin"

Answer (score 0):

The part `sudo -u ejabberd` means the command shall be executed within the user, who owns your `ejabberd` process. Usually this should be an unprivileged user, but maybe your user is called differently or you might even use root. In latter case the command should be like:

```
exec('sudo -u root ejabberdctl register '.$username.' '.$node.' '.$password.' 2>&1',$output,$status);
```

Be aware that running services that are accessible to external networks such as internet should not run as root, because of security reasons!