# Store custom data for each user in ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd

I need to store data for each user in ejabberd.How can I do this ? I mean I need to add one more field to user table and I should update this data whenever.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I am doing.

During registration process in my Android Chat application, I post data like the desired userid (jabberid), password, email, display name, gender, mobile etc. to my PHP API. The PHP code validates if userid already exists and if it doesn't then it creates the user first in an external mysql database, storing all the fields received in post, and then creates the real user in ejabberd by executing the ejabberdctl register command. There will be some permission issues executing the command inside apace\PHP which I successfully resolved using [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626897/create-ejabberd-user-from-php). Now I can access the user data using my PHP API.

The idea is that I am not overloading the mnesia database with rarely accessed or modified data. IMHO, this helps if you don't want to switch ejabberd to odbc\mysql mode and lose potential benefits of mnesia or if you are planning to run mnesia in "RAM Only" mode. All this I am saying with limited knowledge of ejabberd, hence don't take my word as gospel.