# Create user in ejabbred using PHP

Tags: php, ejabberd

Right now I am trying to create a user in ejabberd using PHP. I have checked many sources From Git. As well as I tried to follow the same answer as given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626897/create-ejabberd-user-from-php/1626921#1626921)

But sometimes user is going to be created, and sometimes not, so any debug points.

https://github.com/fabiang/xmpp

As per my knowledge there is issue related to time limit between create user one after another in ejabberd.

For example :
My script is going to run and create a user at a time.

Then I have to wait around 8-9 minutes, then I am try executing my script then it will create another user for me on first try but IF I try to create another user just after some time. 
Is that possible?

CODE :

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
error_reporting(-1);


use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Fabiang\Xmpp\Options;
use Fabiang\Xmpp\Client;
use Fabiang\Xmpp\Protocol\Register;
use Fabiang\Xmpp\Protocol\Roster;
use Fabiang\Xmpp\Protocol\Presence;
use Fabiang\Xmpp\Protocol\Message;
$logger = new Logger('xmpp');
$logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('php://stdout', Logger::DEBUG));

 $hostname      ='192.168.1.12';
 $port           = 5222;
 $connectionType = 'tcp';
 $address        = "$connectionType://$hostname:$port";
 $adminUsername ="admin";
 $adminPassword = "admin";

 $name ="87878";
 $name ="87890";
 $password = "maddy";

 $options = new Options($address);
 $options->setUsername($adminUsername)
        ->setPassword($adminPassword)
        ->setContextOptions(['ssl' => ['verify_peer' => false,'verify_peer_name' => false]]);
 $client = new Client($options);         
 $client->connect();             

 $register = new Register($name, $password);                
 $client->send($register);   
 $client->disconnect();  
  ?>
```

Any suggestions?